# Python Regular Expression throwing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to create regex pattern for the following date variants:
Sample date variants are as below:

- `04/20/2009`
- `04/20/09`
- `4/20/09`
- `4/3/09`

Whenever a similar pattern would be encountered in the input string, dates will be identified matching the defined regex pattern

My Approach:
I have broken down the entire date into month, date and year parts and created regex objects:

```
month = re.compile(r'(^0?[1-9]$)|(^1[0-2]$)').search('04').group()
day = re.compile(r'(^0?[1-9]$)|(^[12][0- 
9]$)|^3[01]$').search('20').group()
year = re.compile(r'(^(19)?\d\d$)| 
(^(20)\d\d$)').search('2009').group()
print(month, day, year)
```

Individually they are working fine and I am getting expected output; for example:
Input string: 
month='04', day='20' and year = '2009' respectively

O/P: 04 20 2009 respectively

Problem Faced:
But while I am combining these three parts(month,day,year) to a single regex pattern, I am getting error.

```
date = re.compile(r'(^0?[1-9]$)|(^1[0-2]$)[/-](^0?[1-9]$)|(^[12][0- 
9]$)|(^3[01]$)[/-](^(19)?\d\d$)|(^(20)\d\d$)')
output = date.search('04/20/2009').group()
```

> Error: AttributeError                             Traceback (most
>   recent call last)  in ()
>         1 date = re.compile(r'(^0?[1-9]$)|(^1[0-2]$)/-|(^[12][0-9]$)|(^3[01]$)/-|(^(20)\d\d$)')
>   ----> 2 output = date.search('04/20/2009').group()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Kindly let me know, where it is going wrong?
How to find the entire date(month,day,year) with the help of a single regex pattern?
Thanks in advance!
Summa

Comment: @Fallenhero Appreciate if you could also show what is the correct way of handling this beside ending the discussion by telling everything is wrong! I have posted my query in a forum like this to correct my mistakes and learn what is better way of coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` means start of line (with multi-line flag) or start of string
and `$` means end of line / string. So adding it to all parts of your regex will result in no match.

Also you want only to match day/month/year grouped

Try:
`^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/-]((?:19)?\d\d|(?:20)\d\d)$`

see: https://regex101.com/r/eZ2Kx1/1/

especially note: `(?:19)` and `(?:20)` those are non-capturing groups

But that is only the regex part. I don't know Python, but I guess match[0] is the complete match, so you probably need to do some more programming here.